# is it possible to override an entity in symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

In my project, I have a bundle which works fine, now I needed to create a second bundle. One entity of my second bundle has the same name as an entity of my first bundle+same fields except it must have two extra fields, and I need the two bundles two work on the same table in the database. How can I extend from an entity in order to add fields and to keep extended ones?

Knowing that I tried the classic inheritence, but I got a beautiful error from doctrine

```
  [Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\SchemaException]
  The table with name 'postgres.article' already exists.
```

No surprise here because the table does exist, How do I do to get doctrine to update it and not try to create it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called [Class Table Inheritance](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html). You can have a parent entity and child entities that extend it. Your additional fields are stored in your child's table and the primary key is linked to the parent table.

The following is a basic example from some of my existing code, you can modify it for your purposes. I have excluded the accessor methods.

Pitfall! When using CTI you must make your properties `protected`, setting them to private will not allow them to be shared.

**Parent Class**

```
/**
 * Item
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="`item`") 
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="type_hint", type="string")
 * @DiscriminatorMap({"physical_item" = "PhysicalItem"})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="\Acme\MainBundle\Entity\ItemRepository")
 */
class Item
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $name;
}
```

**Child Table**

```
/**
 * PhysicalItem
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="`physical_item`")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */

class PhysicalItem extends Item
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="weight", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $weight;
}
```

In this example you would have an item table and a physical_item table. All the properties of item are stored there and the extra properties of physical_item are stored in it's own table. When you use the Entity class you will have joined access to all properties.